# Что не так с вводом строки через указатель в массиве структур?

Tags: c, строки, динамические-структуры

После ввода адреса visual предлагает отладку либо завершение программы

```
    //Ввести массив структур в соответствии с вариантом. Рассортировать массив в алфавитном порядке по первому полю, входящему в структуру. В программе реализовать меню:
    //1)    Ввод массива структур;
    //2)    Сортировка массива структур;
    //3)    Поиск в массиве структур по заданному параметру;
    //4)    Изменение заданной структуры;
    //5)    Удаление структуры из массива;
    //6)    Вывод на экран массива структур;
    //7)    Выход
    //9.    Структура «Пациент»: фамилия, имя, отчество; домашний адрес; номер медицинской карты; номер страхового полиса.
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define MAX_SIZE 256
    typedef struct Patients
    {
        int Num;
        char NameAndLastN[40];
        char *Address;
        int HealthCardNumber;
        long InsuranceNumber;

    } Patients;
    int n;
    Patients *p;
    Patients **m;
    void clear_stream()
    {
        while (getchar() != '\n');
    }

    int main()
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
        m = (Patients**)malloc(sizeof(Patients*));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            p = (Patients*)malloc(sizeof(Patients));
            printf_s("Input Name Last Name and Patronymic:\n");
            clear_stream();
            gets_s(p[i].NameAndLastN);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf_s("Input Address:\n");
            clear_stream();
            gets_s((p+i)->Address, MAX_SIZE);// zdes oshibka
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            free(p[i].NameAndLastN); 
                }
        free(m);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: А ввод имен хорошо работает? Попробуйте объяснить словами (хотя бы себе), что делает код в этих циклах и зачем там переменная `m`.

Comment: Документация по `gets_s` намекает, что это даже не С, а C++

Comment: @andreymal ? обычная себе функция C...

Comment: @Igor С вводом имен все в порядке, а m вводила, чтобы сделать динамический массив структур, может, не совсем правильно, но нигде в литературе не нашла примера, поэтому сделала, как додумалась..

Comment: @Harry тогда вопрос на засыпку: у этой функции один аргумент или два? :)

Comment: @andreymal без MAX_SIZE вообще не получается ввести строку

Comment: @Yana "С вводом имен все в порядке," - как Вы это выяснили? Указатели на структуры нигде не запоминаются, а имена пишутся в совершенно левую память.

Comment: @Igor а можно в соцсети с вами связаться? как я поняла, ошибок хватает, а у меня не получается самостоятельно сделать эту программу, хотя я думала, что не все так плохо...

Comment: @andreymal Конечно, два - но вопрос не в том, правильно ли ее используют, а в вашем *Документация по gets_s намекает, что это даже не С, а C++* - почему это не C, а C++? Или вы хотите сказать, что в C++ у нее один аргумент?

Comment: @Harry в гугле первой ссылкой выдаётся документация майкрософта, которая уверяет, что у этой функции одновременно и один аргумент, и два аргумента. При этом обратите внимание на число аргументов в двух вызовах gets_s в данном коде и на то, что весь этот код успешно компилируется

Answer (score 0):

*Из соцсетей у меня только Skype :).*

Давайте по порядку.

```
typedef struct Patients
{
    int Num;
    char NameAndLastN[40];
    char *Address;
    int HealthCardNumber;
    long InsuranceNumber;
};
```

Вот у Вас в структуре `char NameAndLastN[40];` и `char *Address;`. Первое - отводит место на строку прямо в теле структуры, второе - указывает куда-то наружу и требует дополнительного распредления/очищения памяти. Почему не одинаково?

```
    char NameAndLastN[40];
    char Address[255];
```

Далее, распределение памяти на массив пациентов.

```
    // m = (Patients**)malloc(sizeof(Patients*)); - убрать
    p = (Patients*)malloc(sizeof(Patients) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf_s("Input Name Last Name and Patronymic:\n");
        clear_stream();
        gets_s(p[i].NameAndLastN);
    }
```

*to be continued.*

Answer (score 0):

```
gets_s((p+i)->Address, MAX_SIZE);// zdes oshibka
```

вы нигде не выделяете память под Address, Address у вас это указатель, поэтому когда gets пытается положить туда данные и возникает ошибка.
Далее...

```
free(p[i].NameAndLastN);
```

Зачем вы освобождаете NameAndLastN если вы определили его как статический массив char NameAndLastN[40]? Здесь у вас тоже будет ошибка.